# Asynchronus calls in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I am new to Javascript and Angularjs. I wanted to know , how to call a function asynchronously without waiting for it to return from it.

Please let me know and if there is some example then it would  be very helpful.

Regards,
nG

Comment: [Angular Docs $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Answer (score 1):

Use Angular's [`deferred`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q):

```
function myAsyncFunction() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    //..
    setTimeout(function() {
        deferred.resolve({ message: "resolved!" });
        // or deferred.reject({ message: "something went terribly wrong!!" });
    }, 1000);
    //..

    return deferred.promise;
}

myAsyncFunction()
    .then(function(data){
        // success
        console.log("success", data.message);
    }, function(data) {
        // fail
        console.log("error", data.message);
    }).finally(function() {
        // always
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [deferred](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) to return a promise, you can then resolve the promise once your function is complete. Try something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/adcoxwga/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[])

.service('myService', function($q, $timeout){

    this.someFunction = function(){
        var deferred = $q.defer(); //making a new deferred

        $timeout(function(){
            deferred.resolve('something'); //resolving the deferred with a response
        }, 3000);

        return deferred.promise; //returning a promise
    }

})

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, myService){

    myService.someFunction().then(function(response){ //calling the asynchronous function
       console.log(response); //getting response
    }, function(error){
        console.log(error); //getting error
    });

});
```

Comment: is timeout is required?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of different options ahead of you, but one thing to note is that you have to use a callback or promise for asynchronous activity. Since you are using angular, I'd suggest using promise's.

**Using a promise**

If you are writing an http call to an api, you can use either `$http` or `$resource`. If you start to research angular providers, you will see that `$http` returns a promise, while $resource returns a promise but you must call it specifically to access it. For instance:

someService

```
function someServiceFunction () {
  return $http.get('some/url');
}
```

someController

```
$scope.results = [];
someService.someServiceFunction().then(function(data) {
    $scope.results = data;
});
```

Something to note is that the first returned function is the success scenario and if you declare a second callback, then it is the failure scenario.

If you were to use callbacks in the same scenario:

**Using a callback**

someService

```
function someServiceFunction (callback) {
  return $http.get('some/url')
           .success(callback);
}
```

someController

```
$scope.results = [];
someService.someServiceFunction(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.results = data;
});
```

Here's a link to the [$http provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).
Here's a link to the [$resource provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource).

Cheers!