# How to update an angular directive with async data

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I have a controller which gets json data called content.json. When I render the UI, I can't know if the json is available yet. The controller gets the json data asap when the app loads, it is an array of objects used throughout the entire app for various purposes:

```
vg.ctrls.controller('vg.ctrls.getContentJson', ['$scope', '$http', 
  function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('models/content.json').success(function(data) {
      if(data instanceof Array){
        vg.content = data; // store in app global variable
      } else {
        vg.log('vg.ctrls.getContentJson: data not array.');
      }
      $scope.vg = vg;
      // vg.Content.createMenu(); // Document may not be ready yet.
    });
  }]
);
```

In my UI, I have a navigation menu which is based on the content.json. Obviously a good place to use ng-repeat within a `<ul>`:

```
<li ng-repeat="entry in content">
  <a ng-click="vg.Content.setById(entry.id)">{{entry.title}}</a>
</li>
```

Unfortunately, content.json has not always loaded by the time that the directive is rendered by AngularJS. So, I made a function vg.Content.createMenu() in my app that generates the menu and put it in the callback from $http.get() - but alas, the document is not always ready yet at this point.

I other words, I have two async processes and a function that depends on them both, but I can't tell which one will be done first. I have solved similar problems before without a framework using my own custom events. However, I would like to believe that there is a way of handling this within AngularJS?

How about creating a custom directive that doesn't execute until content.json has loaded?

--------------------- EDIT -----------------------

Here's an intermediate solution:

```
vg.directives.directive('vgContentMenuByCategory', function(){
  return {
    scope: {
      categoryId: '='
      ,title: '='
      ,content: '='
    }
    ,replace: true
    ,link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      scope.$watch('content', function(content){
        var $ul = element.find('ul.dropdown-menu');
        for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
          var entry = content[i];
          if(entry.category===scope.categoryId){
            var $li = $('<li><a>'+entry.title+'</a></li>');
            _goToContentClickHandler({$element:$li, id:entry.id});
            $ul.append($li);
          }
        };
      });
    }
    , templateUrl: 'templates/vgContentMenuByCategory.html'
  }
});
```

This is not really a "proper" solution, though - because I am not using "ng-repeat" in my template but doing so instead within a loop in scope.$watch(). If I use ng-repeat in the template instead, the 'content' hasn't loaded yet. The problem is complicated further because I actually want to use the directive above within another directive that runs through categories - and that also has to wait for content.json to load.

So, how do I make the directive wait with rendering the template or executing any directives within it, before the values have loaded?

Comment: Hack: I currently check on $(document).ready() if the content array is available - if not, I check again 500ms later. When it is there, I run vg.Content.createMenu().

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27889083/how-to-wait-for-asynchronous-data-before-updating-ui-options

Comment: Thanks. In that thread, I don't see any call to server other than templateUrl - no call to json file or service or other server-side url, no callback functions?

Comment: See the code. The idea is have a directive that binds to controller.data. Later a service can update the controller.data. The idea is directive updates content each time data changes.

Comment: It took me a while, but I think I understand now. Will post the solution.

Comment: I just made significant changes to my question as I added a partial solution - which is not entirely good yet, though @EricSonaron

Comment: Could you be a bit more clear in what the actual problem is. You guys sound like severely over-complicating things in angular. Your data is loaded asynchronously. It will be rendered 100% later then the menu container. Period. Would you like to hide the menu before data arrived or show a loading spinner? Why are you trying to delay rendering of the menu?

Comment: The menu is rendered based on an array called window.vg.content. When I use ng-repeat, the menu is empty - because the vg.content variable is still empty at the time that ng-repeat is rendered. The menu remains empty, even after the json file has loaded and the vg.content value has been set. That is the problem.

Comment: I will try out Justin's suggestions below. The source code for my app is here: https://github.com/ellvtr/visiongram01/blob/master/www/js/vg.src.js (work in progress). I build the majority of my app without a framework in the global "vg" namespace. I am beginning to realize, that angular may only work properly in the above case, if I build the entire app inside the framework - for which I need to learn more about what angular can do. Live demo of app here: http://ellvtr.github.io/visiongram01/

Answer (score 0):

Create a content factory:

```
app.factory('Content',function(){ 
            var category; 
            var title; 
            var id;
            return {
                     category:function(){return category;},
                     title:function(){return title;},
                     id:function(){return id;},
};
```

Then in your app.js define a function with a get request to retrieve content and populate a Content object in the app.js scope. Finally, when routing to your controller add this function to the resolve list.
When defining your controller extend the parameters to

```
vg.ctrls.controller('vg.ctrls.getContentJson', ['$scope', '$http', 
  function($scope, $http,Content) {
```

to access the `Content` object.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out - thanks to your comments and answers and to this tutorial: https://youtu.be/rHmk0UhJSb4.

First, I create a service that gets the data and populates it through a method:

```
vg.ctrls.service('vg.ctrls.contentService', ['$http', '$q',
  function($http, $q) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.get('models/content.json').then(function(data) {
      deferred.resolve(data);
    });

    this.getContent = function(){
      return deferred.promise;
    };

  }]
);
```

Then, I create a controller that injects the service and puts the data in the scope:

```
vg.ctrls.controller('vg.ctrls.content', ["$scope", "vg.ctrls.contentService", 
  function($scope, service){
    var promise = service.getContent();
    promise.then(function(o){
      $scope.content = o.data;
    });
}]);
```

Subsequently, directives within the scope of that controller, will be updated when the data has loaded such as:

```
<div class="well" id="test" ng-controller="vg.ctrls.testService">
  <span ng-repeat="entry in content">
    <p>{{entry.id}}: {{entry.title}}</p>
  </span>
</div>
```

Or in a directive like this:

```
vg.directives.directive('vgContentMenuAllCategories', function(){
  return {
      scope: {
        content: '='
      }
    , controller: 'vg.ctrls.content'
    , link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        //vg.log('vgContentMenuAllCategories');
    }
    , template: 
      '<span ng-repeat="entry in content"><a ng-click="vg.Content.setById(entry.id)">{{entry.title}}</a><br/></span>'
  }
});
```

To make sure it works when the data arrives later, I modified the service to fetch the data 5 seconds later - and the directive indeed gets updated when the data arrives:

```
var foo = function(){
  $http.get('models/content.json').then(function(data) {
    deferred.resolve(data);
  });
};
setTimeout(foo, 5000);
```

Comment: Btw, what is wrong with the template `ng-click="vg.Content.setById(\'{{entry.id}}\')"` - it resolves correctly in the html to e.g. `ng-click="vg.Content.setById('SegwayTours')"` whih is valid when executed in the console - but when I click it, it resolves to `vg.Content.setById('{{entry.id}}')` and hence causes an error.

Comment: Oops, got it - no curly brackets at all: `ng-click="vg.Content.setById(entry.id)"` .. :)